# In how many ways can $5$ different colored balls be placed into $8$ bins if no bin contains more than one ball?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, balls-in-bins

5 distinct different colored balls into 8 distinct bins and no bin contain more than one ball, how many ways can the balls be placed into the bins?

I got 8*7*6*5*4=6,720.  But I am unsure if it is right.  My thought process was that the first distinct ball can be placed in 8 bins, the second into 7 bins ect.  and i used the product rule to multiply all the combinations together to get my answer. Any hints or help would be great thanks.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I will point out that this question has nothing to do with probability.  It is instead about counting / enumerative combinatorics.  That you use counting techniques in many probability questions does not make *this* a probability question.